# Unable to Access A Property in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, stripe-payments

I'm new to javascript and I'm working on a project where I need to access the prices property within a JavaScript object. This object is the product object from the stripe integration. When I log productData.prices, it shows undefined even though the productData object has the prices property. I'm not sure why this is happening. Can someone help me understand what might be causing this issue?

Here is the javascript code

```
export default function Subscription() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [stripe, setStripe] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeStripe = async () => {
      const stripe = await loadStripe(
        process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
      );
      setStripe(stripe);
    };

    initializeStripe();

    const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
    getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
      const products = {};
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        products[doc.id] = doc.data();
        const priceSnapshot = await getDocs(
          collection(db, "products", doc.id, "prices")
        );
        priceSnapshot.forEach((price) => {
          products[doc.id].prices = {
            priceId: price.id,
            priceData: price.data(),
          };
        });
      });
      setProducts(products);
    });
  }, []);

  async function loadCheckOut(priceId) {
    setLoading(true);
    const usersRef = doc(collection(db, "users"), currentUser.uid);
    const checkoutSessionRef = collection(usersRef, "checkout_sessions");

    const docRef = await addDoc(checkoutSessionRef, {
      price: priceId,
      trial_from_plan: false,
      success_url: window.location.origin,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    });

    onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (error) {
        alert(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`);
      }

      if (sessionId && stripe) {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="mt-4 mb-4">
        <h1 className="text-center mt-4">Choose Your Plan</h1>
        <Row className="justify-content-center mt-4">
          {Object.entries(products).map(([productId, productData]) => {
            console.log(productData);
            console.log(productData.prices);

            return (
              <Col md={4} key={productId}>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Header className="text-center">
                    <h5>{productData.name}</h5>
                    <h5>$20.00 / month</h5>
                  </Card.Header>
                  <Card.Body>
                    <h6>{productData.description}</h6>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => loadCheckOut(productData?.prices?.priceId)}
                      variant="primary"
                      block
                      disabled={loading}
                    >
                      {loading ? (
                        <>
                          <Spinner
                            animation="border"
                            size="sm"
                            className="mr-2"
                          />
                          Loading...
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        "Subscribe"
                      )}
                    </Button>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

The `console.log(productData);` logs the following object

```
{
    "images": [],
    "description": "Access to dashboard",
    "tax_code": null,
    "active": true,
    "role": "premium",
    "name": "Premium",
    "metadata": {
        "firebaseRole": "premium"
    },
    "prices": {
        "priceId": "price_1N7SdbJHqW6OBlJ5itJgsGON",
        "priceData": {
            "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
            "interval": "month",
            "unit_amount": 2000,
            "currency": "usd",
            "product": "prod_NtF7pDBsqj5psh",
            "transform_quantity": null,
            "type": "recurring",
            "active": true,
            "metadata": {},
            "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
            "tiers": null,
            "tiers_mode": null,
            "interval_count": 1,
            "recurring": {
                "interval": "month",
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "usage_type": "licensed",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "trial_period_days": null
            },
            "description": null,
            "trial_period_days": null
        }
    }
}
```

The `console.log(productData.prices);` logs undefined. Can someone help me understand what's happening here and how i can resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Although I'm sure I know the answer, I would try **console.log(typeof productData);** That will tell you the what data type productData actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided ‍♂️ I think, the way the `products` object show up In the console it like :

```js
{"key":"value"}
```

‍ Here the key is presented as an actual string,‍♂️ in another way the `products` obj is formatted in the console like a `JSON` data, so when you want to access it like `products.property` it will not work unless you parsed from `{"key":"value"}` to `{key:"value"}` using:

```js
JSON.parse(products);
```

it will convert it to an actual javascript object with accessible properties ✨.
or you can use ‍♂️:

```js
products["property"]
```

it should work, hopefully,